# Round function doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, rounding

I'm trying round a Double value with two decimal places:

var x = 0.68999999999999995
   var roundX = round(x * 100.0) / 100.0
   println(roundX) // print 0.69

If print the value is correct.. but the var value isn't that i expect, continue 0.68999999999999995

[image]

I need the Double value... not String like other StackOverflow answers :(

Comment: Try println(round(roundX))

Comment: You can also use the `String` function to format `println(String(format: "%.2f", roundX))`

Comment: If I use String the final value is 0.68 and I need 0.69. @user985366 :/

Comment: One answer in the other thread suggested using NSDecimalRound : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDecimalRound

Comment: The other thread covers Objective-C. Many new Swift developers can't read Objective-C, so that the suggested duplicate answer isn't really a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers like doubles do not have a number of decimal places. They store values in binary, and a value like .69 can't be represented exactly. It's just the nature of binary floating point on computers.

Use a number formatter, or use String(format:) as @KRUKUSA suggests

```
var x:Double = 0.68999999999999995
let stringWithTwoDecimals = String(format: "%.2f", x)
println(stringWithTwoDecimals)
```

Comment: If my answer meets your need you should accept it. Then, when you get enough reputation points, you should up-vote answers that you feel are good answers. (Upvoting is optional. Accepting the first correct answer is pretty much a requirement for SO unless you want people to start ignoring your questions.)